# How to replace the URL using C#

Tags: c#

I have to split and replace the values using C# and want to find the last occurring slash / from a string and replace the contents after the last slash / For example:

> var word = "www.abc/def/ghf/ijk/**default.aspx**";

should become

> var word ="www.abc/def/ghf/ijk/**replacement**";

The number of slashes may vary each time.

Comment: You can do that using [string.LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx) and [string.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) and if you are stuck somewhere then come here and ask that particular question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string word = "www.abc/def/ghf/ijk/default.aspx";
string[] words = word.Split('/');
words[words.Length -1] = "newValueHere"
word = String.Join("/", words);
```

Answer (score 0):

word.LastIndexOf("/"). Get the position and then concatenate the before slash content with the replacement like "slash before + replacement."

Answer (score 0):

```
var word = "www.abc/def/ghf/ijk/default.aspx";
var index = word.LastIndexOf("/") + 1;
word = word.Remove(index, word.Length - index) + "replacement";
```